# How do I make a "for" loop for this sequence of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Well, it's meant to emulate a polynomial of the nth degree. 
So, if n = 2, it would be:

```
[1^2, 1^1, 1^0], [2^2, 2^1, 2^0], [3^2, 3^1, 3^0]
```

When n = 3, it would be:

```
[1^3, 1^2, 1^1, 1^0], [2^3, 2^2, 2^1, 2^0], [3^3, 3^2, 3^1, 3^0], [4^3, 4^2, 4^1, 4^0]
```

So for n = k:

```
[1^k, 1^(k-1), ... 1^(k-k)]... [(k+1)^k, (k+1)^(k-1)... (k+1)^(k-k)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give more details.

Comment: I edited it, let me know if you need any more information
Thanks!

Comment: does your `^` mean difference, or power?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It means to the power of

Comment: my answer does it in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code would help you.

```
array = []
n = 3
for base in range(1, n+1):
    inner_array = []
    # Loop in reverse until 0
    for degree in range(n+1, 0, -1):
        inner_array.append(base ** (degree - 1))
    array.append(inner_array)
print(array)
```

`n=4` omits

`[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [16, 8, 4, 2, 1], [81, 27, 9, 3, 1], [256, 64, 16, 4, 1]]`

Can be turned into a function

```py
def get_polynomial_arrays(n):
    array = []
    for base in range(1, n + 1):
        inner_array = []
        # Loop in reverse until 0
        for degree in range(n + 1, 0, -1):
            inner_array.append(base ** (degree - 1))
        array.append(inner_array)
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with a nested list comprehension:

```
n = 3
a = [[(s+1)**(n-i) for i in range(n+1)] for s in range(n+1)]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [8, 4, 2, 1], [27, 9, 3, 1], [64, 16, 4, 1]]
```

That list comprehension is as:

```
a = []

for s in range(n+1):
    b = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        b.append((s+1)**(n-i))
    a.append(b)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehensions in nested way, which is more Pythonic way, like below:

```py
n = int(input())
poli_list = [[i**j for j in range(n,-1,-1)] for i in range(1,n+2)]
print(poli_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def printPolynomial(n):
    for x in range(1, n+2):
        print('[', end = '')
        for y in range(n,-1,-1):
            print(x,'^',y,end='')
            if y != 0:
                print(', ', end='')
        print(']')


printPolynomial(3)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.